# Can I delete the "left over" files which are selectively not-synced in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, mac

To save space on my local OS X harddrive, I've unselected several folders in the Selective Sync setting of Dropbox. Now, in Finder on my local machine, those folders have a minus sign next to them, but the files in them are still present. Can I safely delete the local copies of the files i.e. Dropbox will maintain copies of those files in the cloud accessible at Dropbox.com?

I ask because the Selective Sync feature says the local files will be removed from my local drive, but they are still there. Seems like I need to remove them manually.

Answer (score 2):

Is the minus symbol gray? If yes, it seems to be a [Selective Sync conflict](https://www.dropbox.com/help/1946/en).

For some reason your folder was not deleted when excluding it from Selective Sync and now Dropbox reminds you that there is a folder with the same name in your Dropbox. This folder is not synced with your local files.

It *should* be save to just delete it, but if you want to be sure do the following:

1. Select the folder in the Selective Sync preferences.
2. You should now have the folder `foldername` with the contents that are also in the Dropbox and a folder `foldername (Selective Sync Conflict)` with the local files that have previously been in your local (unsynced) `foldername` folder. Check it.
3. Unselect both folders in the Selective Sync preferences.
4. Both folders should be gone. Check it.